# Need help : ip logs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip

Connected my personal laptop to office server using personal mobile hotspot. I know server maintains ip logs about my personal laptop which is directly connected to server. But what about my mobile? Does server also records ip logs from my mobile? Asking this because laptop is connected to internet through mobile hotspot. Checked the ip address of mobile and laptop they are same.

Answer (score 0):

The server will also log it. Your mobile and your laptop have the same public IP. Because your phone is acting like a router / modem.